# Show input and output while reading file and interpreting it

Tags: unix, pipe

To test a command line interface I want to read a file and sends it content to the CLI. This can easily be done with

```
cat file | ./my_program
```

or

```
./my_program < file
```

The only problem is its output. It is

```
> command not found
> command not found
>
```

instead of

```
> a
command not found
> b
command not found
> quit
```

when the file to read contains the three lines

```
a
b
quit
```

Is it possible to print the input too and to move the output to the next line?

Comment: wat r u trying to do here ? Do u want to exec ur script with name my_program?

Comment: @Venk: Yes, that is the plan.

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, you can tee the input to /dev/tty:

```
< file tee /dev/tty | ./my_program
```

Note that this will give you the output in which the input is not distinguished with a prompt:

```
a
command not found
b
command not found
quit
```

But you could prepend all the input lines with $PS2 easily enough:

```
< file sed "s/^/$PS2/" | tee /dev/tty | sed "s/^$PS2//" | ./my_program
```

(PS2 defaults to '> ', and if the content of PS2 contains any forward slashes you'll need to modify the sed commands to use a delimiter that does not appear in PS2.)

Comment: on my system your commands first print out the lines of the file and then the output of the program. They are not merged as showed in your example.

Comment: I believe the problem is that your program is writing to stderr, so the interleave is affected by buffering.  To interleave them, just redirect stderr to stdout via 2>&1

Comment: This does nothing change. The output is still the same.